# Matching multible variables in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I've got an `input` into my system, current a current `state`, and a `previous_states`. My first direction of thought would be to use a `when` statement, but Kotlin doesn't support using multiple variables in there:

```kotlin
when (input, state, previous_states) {  
  (KeyPower, PowerOff, matched) -> ...
  (KeyPower, PowerOn,  matched) -> ...
  (KeyMenu,  PowerOff, listOf(MainView, _)) -> ...
}
```

Is just a syntax error. Is there a workaround for this / an entirely different approach?

Comment: Are `state` and `previous_states` the same class? And what is `matched` data type? Something is wrong about `matched` value here

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to indicate that `matched` is the variable `previous_states` gets destructured into. Aka the values don't matter for that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `when` in this case, but you will have to wrap the three independent `var`s/`val`s in a `Triple`.

Here's an example that uses `String`s, because I don't know the types of your `var`s/`val`s:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val input = "KeyPower"
    val state = "PowerOn"
    val previous_states = "matched"
    
    when (Triple(input, state, previous_states)) {
          Triple("KeyPower", "PowerOff", "matched") -> println("Power, Off, matched")
          Triple("KeyPower", "PowerOn",  "matched") -> println("Power, On, matched")
          Triple("KeyMenu",  "PowerOff", "matched") -> println("Menu, Off, matched")
          else -> println("no match")
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Power, On, matched
```

The `when` statement requires a single object, it seems…

Comment: Is it also possible to ignore the third part, aka the third part of the `Triple` doesn't matter for a match?

Comment: Sure, use a `Pair` instead for wrapping the first two values…

Comment: Is it also possible to ignore a part for only one case?

Comment: You'd have to create a Triple that  matches the part you want to ignore. For example, a condition `Triple("KeyMenu", "PowerOff", previous_states)` would be effectively ignoring the third parameter.